# Error in retriving data using GET method in PHP

Tags: php, url, get

I am try to send data through URL and this data contain special characters for example : mustafa+hamid
When I try to retrieve this data the result will be "mustafa hamid" meaning that the + automatically is replaced with space.
How can I retrieve the orginal text??
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following characters

```
# $ & + ,  / : ; = ? @ [ ]
```

are reserved. If you want to send them in variable via GET, you must first "url encode" them first. You must send "mustafa%2Bhamid" instead of "mustafa+hamid" in the URL.

You can use the urlencode() PHP function to see how each of the above character needs to be encoded.

Comment: can you guide me how can I use urlencode..assume we have the following link http://example.com/test.php?d=mustafa+hamid and then how can I use urldecode to retrive orginal text?

Comment: I will quote myself: "You must send "mustafa%2Bhamid" instead of "mustafa+hamid" in the URL."

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript function

```
var encodedURL= "http://www.example.com/test.php?d=" + encodeURIComponent('mustafa+hamid');

//output :http://www.example.com/test.php?d=mustafa%2Bhamid
```

or you can simply replace + with %2B, this is the encoded code for +

Comment: hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment, or I would have. The answer Phillip Petrov gave is technically correct.

Here's an example

```
$data = "mustafa+hamid";
$urlEncoded = urlencode( $data );

// To get the data back to its original value
$originalValue = urldecode( $urlEncoded );
```

[PHP - urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

[PHP - urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)